# Is the box office for 'Approaching the Unknown' really just 10K?

Tags: box-office, approaching-the-unknown

Wikipedia says that the box office for the movie [Approaching the Unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approaching_the_Unknown) is just $10232. That seems ridiculously low for a movie with a budget of 1.3 million. Is this figure correct?

Comment: Seriously, downvotes?

Comment: No idea of votes (probably because there are too many easily google-able box-office websites) and 10k seems small indeed for Mark Strong movie. But the movie ratings are quite poor and 1.3m is not that much of a budget for a movie. And think of this: it came a year after The Martian. Add Solaris and Moon to same category and you get your comparison. It was doomed to failure. With 1.3m you do not get movie-marketing and distribution. And without this you wont sell even if you have a good movie.

Comment: @Paharet: That is probably it. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: @Paharet In hindsight, I should have probably asked how a movie with Mark Strong and the other guy on the monitor could have bombed so badly. Oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this website and its information:

http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=approachingtheunknown.htm

Total Lifetime Grosses

Domestic:  $10,232

Domestic Summary

Opening Weekend:  $6,476 
(#57 rank, 11 theaters, $589 average) 
% of Total Gross:  63.3%

> View All Weekends

Widest Release:  11 theaters

In Release:  7 days / 1 weeks

The Players

Actors: Sanaa Lathan,Mark Strong, Luke Wilson

Yes it is very in fact that.